# PostGIS raster2pgsql problem

Tags: postgis, raster2pgsql

I ran into this problem in PostGIS:

```
raster2pgsql -c -I -C -s 4326  -N -9999  -M -Y  -F ./test2/*.tif  rdem2 > rdem2.sql
```

> Processing 84/84: ./test2/dem2_4326_06_14.tif
>
> ERROR: diff_rastinfo: Could not run raster alignment test

Does someone have any ideas about possible reasons for this problem ?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what data you are trying to import? There could be known issues with known sources of data which can help shed light on your challenges.

Comment: Do you see the error if you do not request to apply constraints? Remove `-C` and try without it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that error might happen if your proj files used by GDAL can not be found.  Alignment relies on that as I recall.

What does:

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

return.  If it returns [GDAL_DATA](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#WhatisGDAL_DATAenvironmentvariable) can not be found, then that's the problem.  Since that is where it looks for the coordinate reference files.

Comment: I should add, if that is the problem, you need to set the environment variable -- GDAL_DATA and it should point at the folder installed by gdal that contains files like compdcs.csv, gcs.csv.  On linux I think its in share/gdal   and on windows it gets installed in PostgreSQL install folder in a folder called gdal-data